# How to create wanted format Devexpress Gridview?

Tags: devexpress

[image]

I am trying to make my gridview look like the picture that i uploaded.

Comment: what item line?? What have you tried so far and what exactly you trying to implement..

Answer (score 1):

you can activate AllowCellMerge in your gridView as :

```
Gridview1.OptionsView.AllowCellMerge = True
```

and by handling the GridView.CellMerge event as :

```
 Private Sub Gridview1_CellMerge(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CellMergeEventArgs) Handles Grid.CellMerge
        If e.Column.FieldName ="Tarih" or e.Column.FieldName <> "Nevi" And e.Column.FieldName <> "BigBag No" Then

            e.Handled = True
            e.Merge = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

For move detail have a look at this [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1461)

Answer (score 0):

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1461
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2472

This samples can help you. You have to subscribe row merge event.